# I got a message from the log and it says: Error: request for member "height" in something not a structure or union

Tags: c, structure

Here's my code, sorry if it is beginners type of program. I was not able to fully enter classes this finals so i don't really know that much about structures. Please help :(

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void add();
void search();
void update();
void bmi();
int age();
void display();

struct rec{
    char fn[30], mn[30], ln[30], gen[30];
    int month, date, year;
    float height, weight;
};

void main() {
    int i;
    printf("1 - Add Records\n");
    printf("2 - Search Patient\n");
    printf("3 - Update Patient Record\n");
    printf("4 - Display Saved Records\n");
    printf("5 - Calculate Body Mass Index\n");
    printf("6 - Calculate Age\n");
    printf("Enter a number to select an entry:");
    scanf("%d",&i);

    if(i==1) add();
    else printf("Invalid number!");
}

void add(rec){
    int a,n;
    struct rec patient[50];
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("recordsfinals.txt","a");
    if(fp==NULL){
        printf("File does not exist!");
    }
    printf("Enter number of entries to append:");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    for(n=1; n<=a; n++){
        printf("Enter Firstname:");
        scanf("%c",&patient.fn);
        printf("\nEnter middle name:");
        scanf("%c",&patient.mn);
        printf("\nEnter last name:");
        scanf("%c",&patient.ln);
        printf("\nEnter gender:");
        scanf("%c",&patient.gen);
        printf("\nEnter Date of Birth\n Month:");
        scanf("%",&patient.month);
        printf("\nEnter Date:");
        scanf("%d",&patient.date);
        printf("\nEnter Year of birth:");
        scanf("%d",&patient.year);
        printf("Enter height:");
        scanf("%f",&patient.height);
        printf("Enter weight:");
        scanf("%f",&patient.weight);
        fprintf(fp,"%c, %c, %c, %c, %d, %d, %d, %f, %f", patient.fn, patient.mn, patient.ln, patient.gen, patient.month, patient.date,  patient.year, patient.height, patient.weight);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Not only height but other variables have the same problems as well.

Comment: You need to review the lecture where they explain what  `struct rec patient[50];` and `&patient.something` mean.

Comment: Please consistently indent the code for easy readability/understandability by us humans.    Never use tabs for indenting as each word processor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set differently.  Suggest using 4 spaces as that is easily visible even with variable width fonts and does not quickly eat up the page width.   In general, indent after every opening brace '{' and un-indent before every closing brace '}'   It is also a good idea to separate code blocks (for, while, if...else, do...while, etc) with a blank line.

Comment: the declaration of the main() function only has 2 valid (and one optional) formats.  All the declarations of main() have a 'int' return type, not 'void'.  The valid formats: `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`   `int main( void )` and the optional format: `int main()`   Strongly suggest when compiling, to always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.

Comment: when entering function prototypes, where there is no parameters, use `( void )`.   Note the actual function declaration/body does not need the `void` so can be written as: `()`

Comment: when calling `scanf()` and family of functions, always check the return value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: Suggest, when checking a numeric value, like the 'i' in the posted code, for some range of values, it is much cleaner/clearer to use a `switch()` statement with a `case` for each of the valid values and a `default` to catch any invalid input.   The switch() is much easier to understand than a long string of if/elseif/else statements

Comment: when an error occurs, like a failure of the call to `fopen()`, do not continue to execute the code as if the `fopen()` were successful

Comment: since the available space (struct rec patient[50]) only allows for 50 entries, the prompt to the user and the validity checking of the 'a' variable should be to assure the input is in the range 0...50.   Note: 50 is a 'magic' number.  'magic' numbers should not be used in the code.  instead #define a meaningful name for the 50 and use that meaningful name throughout the code

Comment: @user3629249 `int main()` is not prototype-style and not an option since C99 (it shall generate a warning) and will not be allowed in future standards, so it should not be used anymore.

Comment: the function `add()` is prototyped to have no parameters, so do not introduce a parameter in the function declaration/body

Comment: Read a book and learn. SO is no tutorial site!

Comment: in C, array offsets begin with 0, not 1 and end with array length -1;  so this line: `for(n=1; n<=a; n++)`  should be: `for(n=0; n<a; n++)`

Comment: when referencing fields in a struct, in an array of structs, it is necessary to select which instance of the struct is being modified, along with which field with the struct.  So, for example, instead of `patient.fn` the reference should be: `patient[n].fn`.

Comment: in C, when an array name is used (there are exceptions to this) then the name degrades to a pointer to the first address of the array,  Also, the format specifier '%c' only inputs a single character (and does not skip over leading `white space`).   The first few fields of the `struct rec` are defined to be arrays of character, so need to use '%s',  however those fields have a max length so  use '%29s' (one less than actual max length).  '%s also does not skip leading `white space` so this line: `scanf("%c",&patient[n].mn);`  should be: `if( 1 != scanf("%29s",patient[n].mn) ) ) { // error }`

Comment: this line: `scanf("%",&patient[n].month);`  should be: `scanf("%d",&patient[n].month);`  (it is missing the format specifier)

Comment: @Olaf,  I'm running ubuntu linux 14.04 and using gcc for compiles/links.  I compile with `-std=c99`  and the `int main()` does not raise a warning

Comment: there are a bunch of other problems, but the above comments should get you headed in the right direction.

Comment: @user3629249: You are right, sorry. Just tried with `-std=C11 -Wall -Wextra` and it also does not warn (Kubuntu 14.04, too). However, the standard clearly lists it for obsolescence and to be removed in a future release, so it should not be used. It also has a different meaning than `f(void)` and the other valid declaration.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is telling you that this type of expression isn't valid:

```
patient.height
```

when `patient` is an array. And `patient` is clearly an array:

```
struct rec patient[50];
```

You cannot treat an array as if it were a structure or union. You need to access one if its elements. For instance

```
patient[0].height
```